# how to automate postgress import and export of functions and views

Tags: database, postgresql

I got some project using PostgreSQL database in legacy, and it uses 19 stored procedures (functions), and some 70 views.

Now, we did some update on live database, and as functions were changed, due to postgres limitation and need to drop and recreate all functions and views, we spent quite some time to do that.

Is there an automated way of changing functions and views in postgress in a way that it takes care about dependencies and do it in proper order.

We have basic views that then create upper level views ... its a bit complex database, at least for me :)

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

I think the easiest way to do this is to backup a database to a text file:

```
pg_dump database_name > database_name.pg_dump
```

They'll be in a proper dependency order, as otherwise restoring a database from backup would be hard. You can edit function and view definitions in the backup file and restore it back to new database.

If database backup file is too big to be edited in your editor, from Postgres 9.2, you can split it to 3 sections:

```
pg_dump --section=pre-data > database_name.1.pg_dump
pg_dump --section=data > database_name.2.pg_dump
pg_dump --section=post-data > database_name.3.pg_dump
```

You'll edit only the first section, which will be small. In older versions you could use for example [`split`](http://unixhelp.ed.ac.uk/CGI/man-cgi?split) utility.

If you cannot afford downtime required for backup and restore it gets trickier. But I'll still recommend working with backup file. Remember that Postgres supports DDL in transactions — if you import functions and views in a transaction and there'll be an error, you can simply rollback all changes, make corrections and try again.

Answer (score 0):

There is no "easy" way.  The best approach IMO is to be prepared first and the set up a way to do this using SQL scripts and version control.

What we do in LedgerSMB is we keep the function definitions in a series of .sql files, which are tracked in subversion.  We then have a script that reloads them.  This will take some work to set up if you haven't done so before.   The easiest way to do this is:

```
pg_dump -s > ddl_statements_for_mydb.sql
```

Then you can copy/paste the function definitions (change CREATE to CREATE OR REPLACE or add  a DROP IF EXISTS where appropriate).  Then you will want to modularize into usable chunks and have a script that reloads all chunks in the right order into your db.  the time and effort that goes into setting up everything now will save many times that in the future because you can apply changes in a predictable way to testing, staging, and production accounts with no appreciable downtime (perhaps even no downtime at all depending on how you structure it).